# How do I make javascript-mode not turn all 8 spaces into tabs?

Tags: javascript, whitespace

[image: A tabified file showing spaces and tabs]

This is what `javascript-mode` generates with standard tabbing (I never hit the space key when making it). I'd like to have the files contain no tab characters. I can't seem to find any option in the Easy Customization mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The buffer-local `indent-tabs-mode` variable controls this (in general, for any mode).

Note that `javascript-mode` is an *alias* for `js-mode`, so there isn't a `javascript-mode-hook`.

```el
(defun my-js-mode-hook ()
  "Custom `js-mode' behaviours."
  (setq indent-tabs-mode nil))

(add-hook 'js-mode-hook 'my-js-mode-hook)
```